# Is filtering the unpacked dependency actually supported in 2.5.2

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to filter an unpacked dependency like this:

```
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/opt/foo</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>${project.groupId}:common:*:tomcat</include>
        </includes>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
```

The files are copied all-right, but the filtering is not applied (tried both `@` and `${*}` style).

This was broken before in several versions, so my question is -- does it work in 2.5.2?
I tried to switch to 2.5.1 but it has another bug that makes the assembly fail.

[This blog](http://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2012/11/maven-dependency-unpacking-filtering-in.html) claims it's not supported and provides a workaround.

Related tickets

- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-327
- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out filtering **is** supported.

Debugging the assembly plugin revealed I was just being stupid and made a typo in the placholder.